# Category SideMenu with button SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, button, textfield, residemenu

i currently developping an app, which allow users to make an research by title, category, price and location.

to be more user-friendly, i'm trying to create a sidemenu, which contains all category under the form of button, and when the button is select, the textfield will take the name of the category.
Furthermore, i want sidemenu appear when the category textfield is tapped.

I used SWRearViewController, for the side menu, but i don't know how to implement the functionnality  which are listed above.

This is an example of what i want to create :

[image: Sidemenu Button]

Thank's for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You should set callbacks for all your category buttons. Once those get triggered you should get the instance of category textfield and set its text, something like

```
func artsCategoryTapped(aButton: UIButton) {
categoryTextField.text = "Arts"
}
```

I'm not sure how `SWRearViewController` works, but if you know how to trigger it, you can set delegate method for your category textField. Once you know someone has begin to edit it, you should display your `SWRearViewController`